# Google Chrome Not reading Jsfiddle program

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsfiddle

If you enter http://jsfiddle.net/WQCav/ with Google Chrome you will see that they are lines in the Result after you click on the black image.
Where do these lines come from if i didn't write them in the code ?
And why is the problem only with Google Chrome ??

Comment: For whatever reason, it seems like just a rendering issue within the jsfiddle page. If you view the page via http://jsfiddle.net/WQCav/show you will see that the lines do not appear. I don't know the cause of them, but they shouldn't be a "real world" problem.

Comment: +1: i admire the problem you've created

Comment: also if you switch tabs, eventually the lines dissappear

Comment: Can't see the issue.. particular version?

Comment: Does this fix it; http://jsfiddle.net/32DVZ/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a coding issue but actually a bug in certain versions of Google Chrome, as unlikely that may sound. I guess there isn't any fix as of now, we just need to wait for Google to resolve their problem, knowing Google that will be done from the moment they find out about it. Let's hope.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known rendering bug from Google Chrome, it has been fixed in recent versions of Chromium (Version 20.0.1132.57 for example), the fix should quickly go upstream to the Google Chrome codebase.